# items are not staying inline when hover

Tags: html, css

I have a list of images that are inline. When I hover an image it will show a background with some width and height appear.

My problem is that, when I hover first item for example, the last one or last 2 are going under the first one and I don't want that, I want to stay inline, and if there are no spaces for them in the .content, they must  disapppear in order to let the .item:hover create his spaces for showing the background with his width/height.

Also, when I hover last 2 images, its glitching..

This is my code (check on fullscreen)

```css
* {
   color: yellow;
}

img {
    width: 270px;
    height: 300px;
}

.content {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 250px;
    height: 350px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    margin: 10px;
}

.item:hover {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 350px;
}

.item:hover .item-description {
   width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: 20px;
    position: relative;
    transition: transform 1s ease-in-out, opacity 1s ease-in-out, visibility 1s ease-in-out, height 1s ease-in-out, width 1s ease-in-out;
}

.item:not(:hover) .item-description {
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: unset;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item-img">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="item-description">
            test
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item-img">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="item-description">
            test
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item-img">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="item-description">
            test
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item-img">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="item-description">
            test
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item-img">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="item-description">
            test
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item-img">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="item-description">
            test
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: inline block does not work in a flex container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `flex-wrap: nowrap;` on your `.content` and none of the cards are going to the next line when hovering. Please view the snippet.

```css
* {
   color: yellow;
}

img {
    width: 270px;
    height: 300px;
}

.content {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.item {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 250px;
    height: 350px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    margin: 10px;
}

.item:hover {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 350px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.item;hover .item-description {
   width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: 20px;
    position: relative;
    transition: transform 1s ease-in-out, opacity 1s ease-in-out, visibility 1s ease-in-out, height 1s ease-in-out, width 1s ease-in-out;
}

.item:not(:hover) .item-description {
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: unset;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item-img">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="item-description">
            test
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item-img">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="item-description">
            test
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item-img">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="item-description">
            test
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item-img">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="item-description">
            test
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item-img">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="item-description">
            test
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item-img">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="item-description">
            test
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** Added `flex-shrink: 0;` to `item:hover` to preserve the `1000px width` Also, I added `overflow: scroll;` on the same class so you can scroll horizontally to see the content that overflows.

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
   color: yellow;
}

img {
    width: 270px;
    height: 300px;
}

 .content {
     width: 100%;
     margin-left: 20px;
     margin-top: 20px;
     display:flex;
     flex-wrap:nowrap;
     overflow:auto
 }

.item {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 250px;
    height: 350px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    margin: 10px;
}

.item:hover {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 350px;
}

.item:hover .item-description {
   width: 1000px;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: 20px;
    position: relative;
    transition: transform 1s ease-in-out, opacity 1s ease-in-out, visibility 1s ease-in-out, height 1s ease-in-out, width 1s ease-in-out;
}

.item:not(:hover) .item-description {
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: unset;
}
```

```html
<div class="content" >
            <div class="item">
                <div class="item-img">
                    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="item-description">
                    test
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="item-img">
                    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="item-description">
                    test
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="item-img">
                    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="item-description">
                    test
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="item-img">
                    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="item-description">
                    test
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="item-img">
                    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="item-description">
                    test
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="item-img">
                    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="item-description">
                    test
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I've tried and is not working.

Comment: i used this code and its working. you want the images to stay inline and just move to right when you hover an image right? this works exactly like that. replace your .content style with the display and flex-wrap and add overflow. i edited the answer

Comment: You should copy the snippet down here and add your changes to demonstrate.

Comment: Yes, but the blue background is not showing fully (at 1000px). I think is stretched.

Comment: i provided the full code. i also changed .item:hover .item-description width to achieve what you want. please check.